# JNDI exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/Referenceable & java.io.NotSerializableException (Jackrabbit JCA 2.21.14 on Wildfly 24)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi, jackrabbit

I have a jackrabbit JCA repository deployed on wildfly 24 (I have to do without elytron because client still in java 7).

I have a series of exeptions during the connection :

```
Exception in thread "naming-client-message-receiver-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/Referenceable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:948)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:59)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.Referenceable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 29 more
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.mycompany.testnewjcr.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.writeSuccessResponse(RemoteServerTransport.java:479)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:210)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:123)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:432)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.cachedConnectionManager
    in object org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl@664d5391
    in field org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCARepositoryHandle.cm
    in object org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCARepositoryHandle@161283b5
    in object org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCARepositoryHandle@161283b5
Exception in thread "naming-client-message-receiver-2-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/Referenceable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:948)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:59)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.Referenceable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 29 more
```

My client doesn't do anything special though :

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        //env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
        
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "****");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "****");
        
        env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        InitialContext remoteContext = new InitialContext(env);

        RemoteRepository rr = (RemoteRepository) remoteContext.lookup("jcr/local");
        Repository repository = null;
        if (rr != null) {
            ClientAdapterFactory adapter = new ClientAdapterFactory();
            repository = adapter.getRepository(rr);
        }
```

My dependencies are correct:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jca</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Wildfly config :

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
                           <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.21.14.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <archive>
                        jackrabbit-jca-2.21.14.rar
                    </archive>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/jcr/local" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="jackrabbit-jca-Pool" use-ccm="true">
                            <config-property name="bindSessionToTransaction">true</config-property>
                            <config-property name="homeDir">/mnt/backup/jcr</config-property>
                            <config-property name="configFile">/mnt/backup/jcr/repository.xml</config-property>
                            <security>
                                <application/>
                            </security>
                            <validation>
                                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                            </validation>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

And Archive validation disabled.

I've been going around in circles for a while now, and there are few resources on the internet about jackrabbit, even less with JCA, and nothing recent especially...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why is your client bom 10.0 while on WildFly 24 ? It should be 24.0.1.Final

Comment: Because our client must be in java 7. The challenge is to upgrade our old repository which is on JBoss 5.1 to the latest and most compatible application server, our application server not having this constraint because new installation (and it deploys only jcr).

Comment: 10.0.0.Final is the latest java 7 compatible just like jackrabbit-jca.
I was hoping to find the best compromise between the java 7 constraint for the client and the latest compatible application server (and jackrabbit too).

Comment: I'm sick of jackrabbit, if I had no choice I would have moved on to something else a long time ago.
Wildfly 10 with open-jdk 1.8 and jackrabbit 2.14.9, deployment error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jcr.RepositoryException from [Module "deployment.jackrabbit-jca-2.14.9.rar:main" from Service Module Loader]
In a few years I've spent dozens of hours trying to get jackrabbit JCA to work, but I have the impression that no one uses it any more as far as my google searches go, and rightly so...